# Azure AD error while parsing OAuth2 callback: invalid_client

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an application registered in Azure AD using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
When trying to login to my app to connect to Microsoft Login. I am getting invalid client error. In logs I seen following error.

```
error=invalid_client&error_description="AADSTS650052 The app needs access to a service (https://aks-aad-server.azure.com) that your organization xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions"
```

Note: I have Microsoft Office 365 standard subscription plan,

Comment: Could please share how you are sending the request? There are many reason for this error. Your request parameter need to have a look.

Comment: I was using aks id for `User.Read` scope which redirects me to aks-aad-server.azure.com, I fixed this after azure support helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the wrong `scope` in the oauth2-proxy configuration which sending incorrect request to azure and after updating the `scope` to correct the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> AADSTS650052 The app needs access to a service (https://aks-aad-server.azure.com) that your organization
> xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx has not subscribed to or enabled.
> Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service
> subscriptions

***To resolve the above error, please check the below workarounds***

- While registering the application in Azure AD, check the supported
  account type you have selected
- If you selected **“single tenant”** you can’t login to your application
  from different tenant
- To access your application from different tenant update supported
  account type to **“multi-tenant”**

To know how to do that in detail **refer** this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-registration-to-be-multi-tenant

- After registering the application, navigate to **Exposing an API**
  and **set App ID URI** and **Add required scopes** such as read, user
  impersonation etc.
- Add Client ID of your Application to ***knownClientApplications***
  parameter in the Manifest

Your admin needs to accept the consent prompt to access this application use the below URL by  updating the ClientID parameter with your application client-id

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=1a8e25b8-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&prompt=admin_consent&response_type=code
```

When your admin granted those permission, you can login to your
application successfully

**Reference :**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/28697/invalid-client-aadsts650052-the-app-needs-access-t.html